# UITest code coverage report - Is there any way to merge multiple .xccovreport?

Tags: ios, code-coverage, xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing, uitest

For some reason, I need to execute UITest through xcodebuild commandline tool for several times. A xccovreport will be generated for each xcodebuild execution. So I will obtain many xccovreports. Is it possible to merge these reports?

Answer (score 0):

As of Xcode 10.2 you can now `xcrun xccov merge [--outReport] [--outArchive] report1.xccovreport archive1.xccovarchive report2.xccovreport archive2.xccovarchive ...` to create one xccovreport file. For more information you can see: https://shashikantjagtap.net/xccov-diff-and-merge-swiftios-code-coverage/